# New and Edit Changeset when creating association for the first time via Edit

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I have 2 different changesets for Company (new & edit). Reason being, I want a simpler registration process (just requiring name) than when editing (optional address).

The test below throws the following error:

> attempting to cast or change association `address` from `Company` that was not loaded. Please preload your associations before manipulating them through changesets

How/why would I preload an association that doesn't exist yet?

CHANGESETS:

```
def new_changeset(struct, params \\ %{}) do
  struct
  |> cast(params, [:name])
  |> validate_required([:name])
  |> cast_assoc(:users, required: true)
end

def edit_changeset(struct, params \\ %{}) do
  struct
  |> cast(params, [:name])
  |> validate_required([:name])
  |> cast_assoc(:address)
end
```

TEST:

```
{:ok, company} = Company.new_changeset(%Company{}, %{name: 'New Co'})
                  |> Repo.insert

changeset = Company.edit_changeset(company, %{name: ..., address: %{}})

assert changeset.valid?
```

#### UPDATE:

Updating the test to retrieve the company and preload the non-existent address AFTER saving, seems to work. Why do I need to do this? Is there an alternative to making an additional SQL query?

```
{:ok, company} = Company.new_changeset(%Company{}, %{name: 'New Co'})
                  |> Repo.insert

co = Company
     |> Repo.get!(company.id)
     |> Repo.preload(:address)

changeset = Company.edit_changeset(co, %{name: ..., address: %{}})

assert changeset.valid?
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that you're passing `address: %{}` along with the `edit_changeset` params, which to Ecto means that you want to update the attributes contained within the `address` association with those you just passed in, which it then expects it to be preloaded.

If you don't intend to change the address attributes, simply remove it from the passed in params:

```
{:ok, company} = Company.new_changeset(%Company{}, %{name: "New Co"}) |> Repo.insert

changeset = Company.edit_changeset(company, %{name: "Updated name"})

assert changeset.valid?
```

Comment: Hi @navinp. Thanks for the response. However, like I mention in the question, the  `edit_changeset` should handle creation of / editng of addresses (address is not present during registration). My real question is why I need to `preload` the association (Go back to the DB) in order to handle the address creation once I have a valid company struct.

Comment: @diano3 did you ever figure out the answer to this?